# save new data to wp_options non-post form

Tags: database, options

I have a form on my front-page. It sends the entered address to Google API and returns the JSON to wp_options. That works fine. I am using update_option to do that, so it rewrites the meta_key each time. How would I go about having each address entered remain?

```
  $address = esc_html( $_POST['address'] );

  //assign JSON object to var using  geocodeing function('address') input 
  $address_results = gmap_geocode($address);

  // transfer data to options array
  $options['py_name'] = $py_username;
  $options['address'] = $address;
  $options['coords']  = $address_results;

  // create and name the option_name and set fields with $options array
  update_option( 'row_name', $options );
```

Comment: It is considered bad practice to save non-settings data in the `wp_options` table because usually the whole table is loaded into memory as it is the settings. If you have a lot of submissions, you could run out of runtime memory. The good practice is to create a new post type and then save each submission as a new post with the various fields saved as post meta.

Answer (score 1):

Load the existing option first and save the new data as an element in an array:

```
// get the option
$data = get_option( 'row_name' );
// add new data to the option
$data[] = $options;
// save it back to the db
update_option( 'row_name', $data );
```

Your option will then be an array of arrays instead of just a single array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [py_name] => username
            [address] => addy
            [coords] => results
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [py_name] => username
            [address] => addy
            [coords] => results
        )
)
```

Comment: I did it like this: ```   update_option( 'py_menu_item_' . sanitize_key( $py_username ), $options ); ```   This seems to do the trick, it gives a unique row_name each time now.

Comment: @user56258 but then you have to query for each row individually which is far less efficient. you could key the array to username like `$data[$py_username] = $options` in the above example and send just a single query to the database to fetch your data.