# How do I use update_option to give me a new option name each time a form is submitted?

Tags: database, options

How do I use update_option to give me a new option name each time a form is submitted? The code I'm using now overwrites the database value. Instead I need to have a new address saved each time.

The code:

```
                    // assign addrss to var
                    $address = esc_html( $_POST['address'] );

                    //assign JSON object to var using geocodeing function('address') input 
                    $address_results = boj_gmap_geocode($address);

                    // transfer data to options array
                    $options['py_name'] = $py_username;
                    $options['address'] = $address;
                    $options['coords']  = $address_results;

                    // create and name the option_name and set fields with $options array
                    update_option( 'py_menu_item', $options );
```

Comment: There is an answer to your [other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125605/save-new-data-to-wp-options-non-post-form)

Answer (score 0):

To update a new option name each time you need something unique to be used as option name so may be using 'time' in the option name

```
$now = new DateTime();
$mytime = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');    // MySQL datetime format
// $now->getTimestamp();           // Unix Timestamp

$option['prefix-'.$mytime] = 'your value';
```

Then you can update as you wish.

To recall it will be a bit hard code. You have to get all value that start with prefix and manual parse the date time to get the newest one.  This method is easy to create but a bit more step when using.

Hope it help

Answer (score -2):

submit data as array, and add to array before submit

```
$all_data = get_option('all_data', array());

$all_data[] = $new_data;

update_option( 'all_data', $all_data );
```

Comment: A better explanation of the code would be helpful.

Comment: And how is this answer different from the one @Milo gave to your [other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/125608/21376)?

Comment: this is the same question, if you compare the code you can see that it is identical

Comment: And that means you can copy Milo's answer and paste it here without so much as a hat-tip to Milo? That was the point.